# Summarize occurrences by area and then by custom groups

Tags: r

I have below dataset that takes a 2 column dataset and creates age group categories depending on stated CustomerAge.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    
    df <- 
      read.table(textConnection("Area   CustomerAge
    A 28 
    A 40
    A 70
    A 19
    B 13
    B 12
    B 72
    B 90"), header=TRUE)
    

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    # Create categories
    Customer_Age_Group = dplyr::case_when(
      CustomerAge <= 18            ~ "0-18",
      CustomerAge > 18 & CustomerAge <= 60 ~ "19-60",
      CustomerAge > 60             ~ ">60"
    ))
```

What I am looking to achieve is an output summary that looks like the below:

| Area | Customer_Age_Group | Occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0-18 | 0 |
| A | 19-59 | 3 |
| A | >60 | 1 |
| B | 0-18 | 2 |
| B | 19-59 | 0 |
| B | >60 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include also 0 occurences you need `count()`, `ungroup()` and `complete()`:

```
df2 %>% group_by(Area, Customer_Age_Group,.drop = FALSE) %>% 
count() %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
complete(Area, Customer_Age_Group, fill=list(n=0))
```

This will show also 0 occurences.

To sort for Area and Age group:

```
df2 %>% group_by(Area, Customer_Age_Group,.drop = FALSE) %>% 
count() %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
complete(Area, Customer_Age_Group, fill=list(n=0)) %>% 
arrange(Area, parse_number(Customer_Age_Group))
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't sort by Area and then by my chosen order for Customer_Age_Group though - for each area, I need row 1 to be 0-18, row 2 to be 19-59 and row 3 to be >60. Can you please advise an amendment that includes this?

Comment: Yes it's easy. I edited the answer to fit your request.

Answer (score 0):

`group_by` and `summarise` is what you're looking for.

`df2 %>% group_by(Area, Customer_Age_Group) %>% summarise(Occurences = n())`

However note that this won't show categories with zero occurences in your data set.